# Jenkins - copy files to web folder permissions denied

Tags: linux, jenkins, permissions, continuous-integration

I have added jenkins to the www-data group

```
jenkins : jenkins www-data
```

Which owns my html folder

```
drwxrwxr-x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Sep  4 14:18 html
```

I try and copy a folder from the build

```
cp -R resources /var/www/html
```

but I get the errors

cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/html/resources/assets/js/app.js': Permission denied

all the files and subfiles are owned by www-data and in the www-data group but I still get the error

**cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/html/resources/assets/js/app.js': Permission denied**

Comment: check permissions for resources, assets and js folders

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 30 15:06 js
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug  2 09:29 sass

Comment: exactly - members of www-data cannot write into them!